# android view draw performance

Tags: android, performance, animation, view, draw

I have a custom view and in `onDraw()` method I draw some images on canvas depending on some parameters. But I have a performance issue, because while this view plays a rotate animation, every time `onDraw()` method is called and it works very slow. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: are u trying this on a real device or on the emulator?

Comment: on a real device, a HTC Desire

Comment: maybe you should change your whole images to one image (take a snapshot or something) this will enhance the onDraw performance by drawing one large image

Comment: as a last solution, it would work like you said. But I want to know if I can prevent this happening from android sdk

Comment: prevent the calls to the onDraw?

Comment: yes, because nothing is changed in my view while it plays the animation

Comment: no if that is happening, then this is how an animation is applied to a view: a transformation is applied onDraw. so it will be called around 30 times per second i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement inside the onDraw() method?

You should use canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap,Matrix,Paint) and only preRotate the Matrix.

Also, you can prevent calling onDraw excessively by calling "invalidate()" method carefully only when you are sure there's an update.